# MUI Card component - make the whole card clickable on mobile but not on desktop

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using the MUI card component to build out a layout. On mobile screen sizes, I want the whole card to be clickable. While on desktop, I want there to be a button instead and the card itself is not clickable.

This is what I have so far:

```
const MyCard = () => {
    const handleClick = () => {
        console.log("Clicked!")
    }
    
    return (
        <Card>
            <CardActionArea onClick={handleClick}>
                <CardContent>
                    <Typography>My Title</Typography>
                </CardContent>
            </CardActionArea>
            <CardActions className="click-me-button">
                <Button onClick={handleClick}>Click me!</Button>
            </CardActions>
        </Card>
    )
}
```

CSS

```
.click-me-button {
    display: none;
 
    // Only show "Click me" button on desktop sizes
    @media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Now, I want add a `disabled` attribute to `CardActionArea` so that it is unclickable on desktop sizes and clickable only mobile sizes. However, I don't know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `useMediaQuery` to handle functionality

```
import useMediaQuery from '@mui/material/useMediaQuery';

const MyCard = () => {
    // you can change maxWidth for mobile devices
    const matches = useMediaQuery('(max-width:600px)');

    const handleClick = () => {
     // add you functionality here 
    }
    
    return (
        <Card >
            <CardActionArea onClick={matches ? handleClick: undefined}>
                <CardContent>
                    <Typography>My Title</Typography>
                </CardContent>
            </CardActionArea>
            {/* hide card actions on larger screens */}
            <CardActions sx={{ display: { xs: 'block', md: 'none' } }} className="click-me-button">
                <Button onClick={handleClick}>Click me!</Button>
            </CardActions>
        </Card>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `useMediaQuery`

```
import { useMediaQuery } from "@mui/material";

const MyCard = () => {
  const handleClick = () => {
    console.log("Clicked!");
  };

  const isMobileScreen = useMediaQuery("only screen and (max-width: 900px)", {
    noSsr: true
  });

  return (
    <Card>
      <CardActionArea
        // method 1
        // onClick={handleClick}
        // {...(!isMobileScreen && { disabled:true } )}

        // method 2
        {...(isMobileScreen ? {
          onClick: handleClick,
        } : {
          disabled: true
        }
        )}
      >
        <CardContent>
          <Typography>My Title</Typography>
        </CardContent>
      </CardActionArea>
      {!isMobileScreen && (
        <CardActions>
          <Button onClick={handleClick}>Click me!</Button>
        </CardActions>
      )}
    </Card>
  );
};

export default MyCard;
```